# FineUploader Drag-and-Drop Issue in Chrome

Tags: jquery, file, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, fine-uploader

I've been working on implementing the [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) within an application and have encountered a minor issue (*which isn't a deal-breaker*) but I am just curious as to why it may not be working.

The Drag-and-Drop functionality doesn't appear to be working at all within Chrome (*however it works perfectly fine using IE 10*). I've tested it numerous times to try and figure out exactly what could be going wrong.

I'm currently using the following code to handle the actual FineUploader itself :

```
<!-- All notable FineUploader and jQuery References here -->

<!-- Actual FineUploader Declaration -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('#uploadarea').fineUploader({
         request: {
             endpoint: "server/uploadHandler"
         }
    });
 });
</script>
```

along with the following very basic markup :

```
<!-- File Uploader -->
<div id="uploadarea"></div>
```

**[Interactive Example](http://jsbin.com/ohebez/1/edit)**

**Note :** that the above example contains far more separate Javascript files than would typically be used for this implementation (*but FineUploader doesn't appear to have a hosted version of their actual jQuery.FineUploader.js file*) but this doesn't really change anything as the results are the same.

I've tried using several different methods of implementing it, such as using a FineUploaderBasic along with the separate drag-and-drop module, however I seem to encounter the same issue with Chrome (*even on the [actual demos from the FineUploader site](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-with-jquery-wrapper-demo.html)*).

I have no extensions running in Chrome and am currently running the latest version (*27.0.1453.110*) using FineUploader (3.6.4) on Windows 8.

Any ideas, comments, or suggestions would be more than welcome as it currently "works" however it would be nice to have the drag-and-drop functionality working in Chrome (*which I figured would be working more easily than IE10*).

Comment: The interactive example you posted, the demo pages, and my own implementation from the develop branch are working for me in Chrome 27.0.1453.110 on OS X.

-- "The Drag-and-Drop functionality doesn't appear to be working at all" --

What exactly do you mean? Does FineUploader fail to register a file dragged upon it? Or is it just not uploading?

Comment: Chrome fails to recognize the drag event at all. For example within IE10 as soon as your begin dragging a file into your browser it fails to detect a "drag event" so that the "Drop Files here ..." drop area appears. (If the box is actually clicked and a file is selected it will upload just fine.)

I've tried this on another machine not running Windows 8 and it seemed to work on there, which leads me to believe that it could be an issue with Windows 8 and Chrome possibly?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and Chrome 27 - no issues.  No other users have reported issues either.

Comment: I'll try Win 8 now...

Comment: Works fine on Win 8, Chrome 27 for me as well.  Tested this on my Win 8 VM as well as a colleague's.  Seems like this is an issue with your environment.  Either way, I am unable to reproduce on the Fine Uploader home page or using the jsbin example you provided.

Comment: Bizarre. I don't have any extensions running within Chrome and my machine is fairly "fresh" as I just recently grabbed a new hard drive so I couldn't think of any issues that might cause that conflict.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your javascript console?

Comment: Negative. However, I just cleared out all of my cache and temporary data within Chrome (basically everything) and now it is working.

Comment: Ha!  That's really weird.

Comment: i have one question that fineuploader and plupload both does the same job....just tell me which one is best in terms of feature and performance. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently - there was a bizarre caching-related issue on my machine that appeared to prevent drag-and-drop functionality from working properly within Chrome.

I cleared out all of the temporary data, cache and everything else from Chrome and it appeared to fix the issue.

Comment: Not the first time a caching issue has bitten someone.  As soon as this issue was reported, I was almost positive that there was something outside of Fine Uploader responsible for this. Any DnD issue in Chrome would likely never make it past my dev machine, as I use Chrome as my primary dev browser.

Comment: Same here. That's probably why I felt it was so bizarre for it to not be working in Chrome but it worked just fine in Internet Explorer 10 (as I always consider Chrome the standard for web-support).